# Why does fopen() change the value of the element in an array?

Tags: c

```
int getbit(int * list, int n)
{
    return (list[n / 32] >> (n % 32)) & 1;
}
void setbit(int * list, int n)
{
    list[n / 32] |= 1 << (n % 32);
}
int main()
{
    FILE * out;
    int size = 99; //2000000000;
    int root = sqrt(size);
    int * list = malloc(size / 8.0); //(2*10^9)/8
    memset(list, 0, sizeof list);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 2; i <= root; i++)
        for (j = 2 * i; j < size; j += i)
            setbit(list, j);
    printf("i=%d j=%d 98=%d\n", i, j, getbit(list, 98));
    out = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    printf("i=%d j=%d 98=%d\n", i, j, getbit(list, 98));
    /*for (i=2; i<size; i++)
    if (!getbit(list, i))
        fprintf(out, "%d\n", i);
     fclose(out);*/
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I use the fopen() in between printf, the value of the third parameter changes from 1 to 0. If I comment out the line then the value is same. What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: using single bits is irrelevant to your problem. Write simpler example, using bytes, ints or whatever. I'm sure the problem is in the single-bit handling, not the `fopen`.

Comment: Without looking at the code, just based on the question, you have a memory error.  Looking at the code, seeing nothing remotely resembling `sizeof *list` in the malloc, you almost certainly have a memory error.

Answer (score 2):

You see undefined behavior: `sizeof(list)` is probably 4 or 8 bytes, depending on the architecture, so `memset` with zeros does not go past the forth byte. You are reading from the third 32-bit *word*, which came from `malloc` and has not been initialized by the `memset` yet. Moreover, you are allocating 12 bytes (`size/8.0` gets converted to `int`; it never makes sense to pass a `float` or a `double` to `malloc`, because you cannot allocate fractional bytes) so accessing the 98-th bit goes past the allocated area.

You should fix these undefined behaviors: allocate enough memory by using

```
// count needs to be a multiple of sizeof(int)
// The math gets pretty ugly here, but it should work:
int count = sizeof(int)*(size+(8*sizeof(int))-1)/(8*sizeof(int));
int * list = malloc(count);
```

Then initialize the data to zero by using the proper size:

```
memset(list, 0, count);
```

Comment: `count` need not be a multiple of `sizeof(int)`. OP should use `uint32_t` instead of `int`, and `count = (size+31)/32` [and `memset(list, 0, count*sizeof *list)`].

Comment: @DanielFischer You are right, I missed that completely! I fixed the math to take `sizeof(int)` into account. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You're writing in memory you do not own, that has an undefined behavior.

Firstly, you're allocating only 12 bytes here:

```
int* list = malloc(size / 8.0);
```

You should do this (just giving you the idea, I don't know how many bytes you really want to allocate..):

```
int* list = malloc((size / 8.0) * sizeof(*list));
```

Secondly, you are memsetting only 4 bytes (if you're on 32bits system) here:

```
memset(list, 0, sizeof list);
```

You should do this:

```
memset(list, 0, (size / 8.0) * sizeof(*list));
```

Finally, the only reason your call to `fopen()` changes things, is because `fopen()` allocates memory.

Good luck.